# Express app deployed to railway, killed error during deployment

Tags: node.js, railway

When deploying express aplliacation with typescript i get an error "killed" when starting server.
I found out that
`import {google} from "googleapis"` is responsible for this error and error is most likely conneceted with memory usage. So my question is how can i get rid of this error, i use googleapis only to authenticate users.